# Qt QVariant toList not working

Tags: qt

I have a Qt (4.7) program that takes a QByteArray and should break it into a list of QVariants, after using a parser to transform it into a QVariant. The problems seem to arise when I try to use the toList() function. I have something similar to this:

```
QVariant var = //whatever the value passed in is...
std::cout << "Data = " << var.toString().toStdString() << std::endl;
QList<QVariant> varlist = var.toList();
std::cout << "List Size = " << varlist.size() << std::endl;
```

which would return this:

```
Data = variant1 variant2 variant3
Size = 0
```

where the size should clearly be 3. Does anyone have an idea what I may be doing wrong? thanks!

Comment: "whatever the value passed in is..." is the entire point. What's the value passed in? Looks like **not** a QVariant wrapping a `QList<QVariant>>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have no idea why, but when I put the command I specified above into a separate function, ie `QList<QVariant> myClass::ToList(QVariant v){return v.toList();}`, and then call `varlist = myClass::ToList(v)`, it works. Still doesn't the original way, but this way it's fine. Guess I'll just chalk it up to one of the quirks of Qt...

Comment: Did you try your first example without calling toString()? Maybe there is a bug in QVariant::toString()?

Comment: @tharibo I had it that way originally, the line with the toString is just a print line for clarification of what the data is at that point. I did try it again without it though, since I still have no clue what it was and am willing to try anything to figure it out haha. Sadly, no change though

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of toList() says:

> Returns the variant as a QVariantList if the variant has userType() QMetaType::QVariantList or QMetaType::QStringList; otherwise returns an empty list.

My guess is, your variant's `userType()` is neither of those two.

You probably need to construct your variant differently, e.g.

```
QVariantList list;
list << variant1 << variant2 << variant3;
QVariant var = list;
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem though is I don't have the individual variants in separate variables; they're all brought into the program together (they're actually originally a QByteArray that is parsed with QJson into a QVariant), that's why I wanted it as a list, to access them separately. Is there a way to it this way?

Comment: In that case you manually need to decompose the byte array in the same way it was composed. Maybe u can use QJson for that as well.

Comment: You need to check `var.type()` value. It seems that `QJson` returns something other than a variant list. If the problem remains, please show `var.type()` value, original json data and code used for parsing.